# Type-checked way of modeling parent-child relationships?

Tags: f#

I have a type, `Item`.  An `Item` may have a parent `Item` *or* one or more child `Item`s *or* neither (ie, there doesn't have to be a relationship, and relationships are at most one level deep).

Transformations on `Item`s sometimes affect the parent, and sometimes the children.  So I need to be able to traverse both ways.

A naive representation is to have a `ParentID: ID option` and `ChildIDs: ID list` fields on `Item`.  But that allows illegal states.

I could instead have a `Relationships` field on `Item` of `type Relationship = ParentID of ID | ChildIDs of ID * ID list | None`, which is better (the `ChildIDs` tuple to ensure there's at least one child in that case).

But is there a way to have the compiler ensure the consistency of the two-way relationship?

I was thinking I could do away with linkages on IDs altogether, and introduce a discriminated union at the very top: `type Item = Item of Item | Compound of Item * Item * Item list`.  (Again, the `Compound` tuple represents a parent, at least one child, maybe more children.)

The downside is now every transformation on `Item` needs to check cases and handle `Compound`s.  (Or maybe this is good since it forces me to think about knock-on effects of every transformation?)

The advantage is that all the `Item`s that a function may need to touch are always available in one, consistent bundle.

Is that "idiomatic"?  Any other approaches to consider?

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work? The Item is a record that contains the payload (ID and data attributes).

The discriminated union defines your four scenarios.

```
type Item = {ID: int; Name:string} //whatever is required

type ItemNode =
| StandaloneItem of Item
| ItemWithParent of Item * Item
| ItemWithChilren of Item * Item list
| ItemWithParentAndChildren of Item * Item * Item list

let processItem (item:Item) = 42
```

Then you could implement your processing of the nodes similar to this:

```
let processNode (item:ItemNode) = 
    match item with
    | StandaloneItem it -> it |> processItem 
    | ItemWithParent (parent, it) -> [parent; it] |> List.map processItem |> List.sum
    | ItemWithChilren (it, children) -> (it |> processItem) + (children |> List.map processItem |> List.sum)
    | ItemWithParentAndChildren (it, parent, children) -> (it |> processItem) 
                                                          + (parent |> processItem) 
                                                          + (children |> List.map processItem |> List.sum)
```

In this way you do not have to add any conditional logic (on top of match) to your processing - you deal with the tuples with known content.

You can also implement records instead of tuples, which will lead to even bigger transparency.

Comment: An item with both Parent and Children doesn't meet the "relationships are at most one level deep" constraint.